# max value from nested list/dictionary - Python

Tags: python

How to do i get this below result from a nested dictionary list?

data_list = `[{'number': 1, 'category': 'orange', 'timestamp': '2020-09-17-10:29:40'}, {'number': 1, 'category': 'peach', 'timestamp': '2019-08-12-10:29:40'}]`

I want the item in list has Max timestamp, hence below is the result i am expecting.
expected result =  `{'number': 1, 'category': 'orange', 'timestamp': '2020-09-17-10:29:40'}`

Comment: `max(l, key=lambda x: x["timestamp"])` because of the format of the dates, it will give the correct result, even though they are strings.

Answer (score 2):

Python's [max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function accepts a keyword-only argument `key`, that defines how the "highest" value should be determined. You can use that to compare the parsed timestamp like this:

```
max(values, key=lambda item: datetime.strptime(item['timestamp'], '%y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: thank you it worked `max(data_list, key=lambda item: datetime.strptime(item['timestamp'], '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'))`